# How does Yamaha DSR-500 from 80's volume slider work?

Tags: pcb

I bought an old Yamaha DSR-500 synth. It had some connectivity issues on the volume slider so I opened it. The slider's pcb side was covered in black stuff which I removed with IPA. However I have no clue hot that is supposed to work.
[image: pcb for the volume slider]

[Red square](https://imgur.com/StzpOum) is the volume slider. I can't hear any beep between the same black portions. As I imagine,
[image: Middle one is for volume]
[this connector in the middle](https://imgur.com/w1OkXyO) should connect the circuit to select volume. Do you have any idea how this should work, or should cleaning be ok? Opening the PCB was pain in the ass so I would rather to have some kind of confirmation on how this should work before assembling the synth again.

Thanks!!

Comment: That black stuff might be a carbon film used for the potentiometer wiper to work against. Without that black film it might never work.

Comment: The black stuff should be conductive, but I would measure the resistance, not rely on the beep of the meter. There is significant wear of the carbon and one of the wipers looks damaged. I’ve not had to repair this type of board before apart from cleaning and and regressing.

Comment: Those black loops and bridges are 7 printed resistors emulating a logarithmic potentiometer.

Comment: If you removed the black stuff, you've destroyed it beyond repair, I'm afraid.

Comment: Always look online for a service manual before trying to repair a synth keyboard. They are complex and may have surprising design choices that lower their cost. This can be a good learning experience for you.

Comment: Thanks everyone! This indeed was a learning experience. I jammed now the slider so that I don't move it anymore before I get something in there. I didn't find a free version of the service manual online. I thought that "I'm an engineer and I can figure this out. (Once again) turned out that I was not able to figure it out. I didn't remove the coating it self but dirt that was on it. After that the sound came a bit better but still had problems with connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black material is "carbon ink printing", used to provide a surface for the slider to operate against.  It's frequently used in keyboards and remote controls and is much cheaper than non-tarnishing precious metals.

Some carbon ink is higher resistance, used for making resistors; some is low resistance for contacts and crossovers.  You can measure yours to see which it is.  Because it's apparently used as a contact surface, it may well be simple low-resistance carbon -- in any case because it's thin and flat it will have negligible resistance.  It's conceivable that it would work with just a cleaned copper surface; or perhaps conductive grease.  It's up to you what you try.  I'd suggest ensuring the wiper fingers a springy and not bent flat; ie, they push hard against the PCB.

The slider appears to be a multiways switch choosing a point in a chain of seven resistors, biggest at left, apparently ground at the right.  Perhaps a signal comes in at the left and is output at the right; perhaps it's reversed.  It may be that the printed resistor ladder is of a different, higher-resistance, carbon ink; or that it's of noticable resistance just from the shape (long and thin and narrow).  If you removed it you're in for some very fiddly repair, but it might just be possible to clean it all off and solder on some very small resistors if you can work out what values they're supposed to be.  You might be able to estimate them if there's any left on your board, from the geometry and from published resistivity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNoyp7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

References:

- A PCB manufacturers' pages about carbon ink [RayPCB](https://www.raypcb.com/carbon-ink-pcb/), [PCB International](https://www.pcbinternational.com/tech/carbonink/), [PCB Asic](https://www.pcbasic.com/pcba-f/carbon_ink_pcb.html), [EuroCircuits](https://www.eurocircuits.com/blog/apply-carbon-contacts-to-pcbs/).  The last one has very good microscope photos.
- Chemical companies' pages about carbon inks of various kinds [Dycotec](https://www.dycotecmaterials.com/products/carbon-pastes/), [Loctite](https://print-your-electronics-with-loctite.com/Carbon-Ink)
- MG Chemicals makes a pen intended for repairing [link](https://mgchemicals.com/products/conductive-paint/conductive-pens/circuit-pen/).
- Forum post about repairing carbon ink keyboards  [link](https://forums.majorgeeks.com/threads/how-to-repair-carbon-conductors-under-rubber-keypads.247237/)

Comment: Thanks! I wrote it unclear so that I cleaned dirt in top of that carbon ink. It had some kind of lubricant which got dirty along the time. So to fix it I need for example that pen, draw it on the exposed copper and then (maybe) add some lubricant?